# Can two keywords be used when I have arguments in Robot frameword?

Tags: selenium, robotframework, ui-automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3QFN.png)

Assign configuration keyword is reused mostly, keyword gets passed in log file but does not click or perform any actions on the UI. Is it because arguments were declared out of it?

Comment: Please don't post an image of code. Take the time to copy, paste, and format it directly in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how the Assign configuration keyword gets passed whilst running this test. But for it to work Arguments used in this keyword should either be passed onto it. Or they should be set up as global or suite variables.

I would pass them on to the underlying keyword like this:

```
Assign Configuration
[Arguments]    ${var_1}   ${var_2}
${Status}    Run keyword and return status    ......
Run keyword if    '${var_1}'=='False' and '${Status}'=='False'    do something
...    ELSE IF    '${var_1}'=='True' and '${Status}'=='True'    do something else
...    ELSE    FAIL    Some error message
Run keyword if    '${var_2}'=='False' and '${Status}'=='False'    do something
...    ELSE IF    '${var_2}'=='True' and '${Status}'=='True'    do something else
...    ELSE    FAIL    Some error message

Enable only auto hidden and reserved
[Arguments]    ${var_1}=True   ${var_2}=False
Assign Configuration    ${var_1}   ${var_2}
```

Also use ELSE IF when using the same variables but with different values and add a FAIL if the values set by the variables can not be processed. In this case if one of the two variables used is True and the other False.